# How do I fix the usb-c port cracking on my pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, hardware

Today I inspected my raspberry pi (4B, 4 GB ram) to see if any cables were disconnected, as my new Viewsonic monitor kept restarting for some reason, and I saw this:[image: Image of raspberry pi with cracked USB-C port]

It looks as if the USB-C port in the image is splitting apart, as the 'teeth' that interlock to hold the port together have... uninterlocked. I'm not at all knowledgeable about this type of issue, and I'd like to know the best way to get this fixed.
I'd also like to know if it's safe to continue using the pi without further damaging the port. I don't know if this helps, but I got it from a [Canakit starter set](https://www.canakit.com/raspberry-pi-4-starter-kit.html) in 2020.

Comment: Yes, I've already seen the tour.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Pi specific question.

I doubt that your connector is "cracking" - far more likely it has been forced by a non-standard plug or strained by wiggling connectors (which should always be pulled straight out).

The USB-C connector should be 8.4mm wide. It it has been stretched you may be able to squeeze with a pair of long nosed pliers.

I have encountered many microUSB connectors from cheap Asian vendors that do not conform to specified dimensions - I do not doubt that there may be cheap USB-C plugs which do not conform to specified dimensions.

It is doubtful that the functionality has been affected.

Comment: Thanks. I know it isn't 'cracking', but I couldn't think of a better word for it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the USB-C port on your Raspberry Pi has been physically damaged, most likely due to stress or strain on the connector. Unfortunately, this is not an issue that can be easily fixed by an average user, as it requires soldering skills and specialized equipment.

In terms of safety, it is not recommended to continue using the Raspberry Pi with a damaged USB-C port, as this can cause further damage to the device and potentially pose a safety hazard. If the port is not able to provide a stable and secure connection, it can lead to intermittent power supply issues, data loss, or damage to any devices connected to it.

Your best course of action is to have the port replaced .

If your Raspberry Pi is still under warranty, you may be able to contact the manufacturer or seller for a repair or replacement.